# faster select in php using mysql call

Tags: php, mysql

my database is laid out with a column named month, and each day of the month listed, with values
[image]

$year = current year

$month = current month

$day = current day

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bk$year WHERE month='$month' ") or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){
       $dbday    = $row['day'];
       if ($day == $dbday) {
        $v1 =   $row['net'];
        $v2 =   $row['gas'];
       }
}
```

is it possible to somehow select that specific day and get the values that correspond using a different programming method maybe in the MySQL call.

edit: I want to replace the if statement and get the specific day with in the MySQL call

Comment: What? I really don't get your question :)

Comment: I want to replace the if statement and get the specific day with in the MySQL call

Comment: You should use the mysqli or PDO extension instead of mysql.

Comment: mysql functions are deprecated. and why dont you use mysql's date type?

Comment: @AlbertD At the *very* least `mysqli`, but PDO is more flexible and generally easier to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bk$year WHERE month='$month' and day='$day' ") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: awesome, I didn't know 'and' worked there, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. First of all, you should be using PDO, but all you need to do is add another condition to your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM bk$year WHERE (month='$month') AND (day = '$day');
```

However, with PDO and prepared statements to handle your arguments it would like this:

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM bk$year WHERE (month= :month) AND (day = :day)";
$stmt = $yourConnectionObject->prepare($select);
$stmt->execute(array(':month' => $month, ':day' => $day));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: This is where you must be sure that `$year` is absolutely, positively a number and not something nasty.

Comment: I've never used your method can you show me how my code would look with your adaption, or explain whats going on here in your code a bit more

Comment: because I get a fatal error @ prepare()

Comment: @tadman yes, excellent point. And Albert D, it's probably because you haven't established your PDO object. There are tons of tutorials on how to do exactly what you're trying to achieve, i find this one very helpful: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score 0):

Add an AND clause : `$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bk$year WHERE month='$month' AND day='$day'") or die (mysql_error());`

And don't use select * in your query, and stop using old mysql_* functions, prefer mysqli or PDO